# Paypal ingoring individual item's discount_rate

Tags: paypal

I am coding html form for PayPal Payments Standard by referring to this [Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) . Below are my current working code.

```
  <input type="hidden" name="item_id_1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="item name 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="715">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="discount_rate2_1" value="10">

  //item 1 with 10% discount

  <input type="hidden" name="item_id_2" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="GST(7%)">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="31.05">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
  //item 2 without discount

  <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="200.00">

  //a total of $200 discount to entire cart
```

The expected amount from above form is

> (715-10%)+31.05-200=474.55

but the current result is

> 715+31.05-200=546.05

below are the summary from paypal for using the above form

[image]

so obviously paypal doesn't count the 10% discount for item 1, the form is working fine before I add in discount_amount_cart , does anyone experience this **when using discount rate and discount amount cart together?**

Comment: Shouldn't it be discount_rate instead of discount_rate2_1 for item 1 and discount_rate2 for item 2 with value="0"?

Comment: Hi , i have try rename discount_rate2_1 back to discount_rate_1 and adding discount_rate_2 with value 0 , but it doesn't change anything , paypal still ignoring the rate

Comment: Scrolling through the docs also suggests that using amount_1 instead of amount_x on items returns the total of the entire cart, though I find the wording to be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation that you linked to, regarding the discount_amount_cart variable:

Single discount amount charged cart-wide. 
It must be less than the selling price of all items combined in the cart. **This variable overrides any individual item discount_amount_x values, if present.** 
Applies only to the Cart Upload command.

If you remove the discount_amount_cart variable, then the others would kick in.  You can't use both.

What you could do, though, if you need to satisfy that scenario is add the flat discount as an additional line item with a negative value as oppose to using the actual discount field for the cart.  Just make it an item with a name "Discount" and set the -200 there.